# Angular mat-icon disappear after modify mat toolbar background color

Tags: css, angular-material, angular-universal

If I define the background color in `.firstrow` class, it impacts the visibility of the svg-icon "logo". To restore original display of the logo I need to enclose it within container and add some css properties again. This behavior is specific to angular universal and does not affects standard browser rendering. Is it possible to avoid re-scaling and coloring if define a custom background color within `firtstrow`?

my.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-toolbar-row class="firstrow">
    <div>Title</div>
    <!--
    <mat-icon svgIcon="logo" class="logoProps"></mat-icon>
    -->
    <div class="logoProps">
      <mat-icon svgIcon="logo" class="logoColor"></mat-icon> 
    </div>   
    <div>Text</div> 
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

my.component.css

```
.firstrow {
  height: 110px;
  background-color: var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
}

.logoProps {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; 
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  filter: invert(86%) sepia(39%) saturate(500%) hue-rotate(349deg) brightness(102%) contrast(87%);  
}
.logoColor {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  filter: invert(86%) sepia(39%) saturate(500%) hue-rotate(349deg) brightness(102%) contrast(87%);
}
```

my.component.ts:

```
...
  constructor( private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
               private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
               @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: string ){
    
    const svgUrl = 'assets/mylogo.svg';
    const domain = (isPlatformServer(platformId)) ? 'http://localhost:4200/' : '';     

    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon("logo", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(domain + svgUrl));
  }
...
```